# Durandal - Correct way to disable .canDeactivate for 'Success' operations?

Tags: durandal

I have an edit page (in a DurandalJS single page app), where I use the `.canDeactivate` lifecycle method to check if there are any changes to the record, and optionally prompt them for confirmation before leaving the page.

I also have a 'Save' and 'View History' button. Is the correct thing to do to override the `.canDeactivate` method before calling `router.navigate`, to stop the modal popup invoking?

E.g.: As here:

```
self.onSave = function() {
    self.repository.updateItem(self.model).done(function() {
        self.canDeactivate = null; // Is this the correct way to do this?
        router.navigate("#/home");
    }
}
```

As this .canDeactivate will otherwise get called:

```
self.canDeactivate = function() {

    if (!self.model.hasChanges()) {
        return true;
    }

    return app.ShowMessage("Unsaved data will be lost", "Are you sure you wish to exit?", ["Yes", "No"]).done(function(result) {
        return result !== "No";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just set

```
self.model.hasChanges(false)
```

in your updateItem callback?

Then when your canDeactivate is called, it will return true.

Also you seem to have an error in your ShowMessage callback. I think you mean to do:

```
return result != "No";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the way Durandal decides whether to attempt to call a `canDeactivate` function is fully defined, other than the fact that if it's not in the view model, it won't try. Hence, even if it works as is, a future version of the framework could change its check to something like `if (canDeactivate in viewModel) viewModel.canDeactivate(...);` without further tests, and your code would break.

This is unlikely, but if you want to worry about it, you should thus `delete self.canDeactivate` instead of assigning it the `null` value.

Quote from the documentation:

> To participate in the lifecycle, implement any (or none) of the
>   functions below on the object that you set the activator to (...)

Current implementation (activator.js, L126, 1eecbc2d3f84dc42eb7304bde761d88f300d8951):

```
if (item && item.canDeactivate) {
```

So it only checks if it's truthy (which would indicate using `null` works fine currently, too).

---

If you want to discuss the pattern, I don't see anything wrong with it, as long as it makes sense to you and everyone who should read the code.

You're not supposed to be activating and deactivating views programmatically in any critical path, so performance should be irrelevant either way (flag on view model or deletion of `canDeactivate`).